# How to avoid anaconda from installing files/packages in C drive?

Tags: python, windows, installation, package, anaconda

If you are using anaconda, then you probably noticed that when installing python packages, it took away the disks in C drive even if you installed anaconda in D drive. (I have tried the clean ect. of conda commands, it's not the cashes or other things but rather useful files.)

This was especially obvious when I was trying to install different versions of tensorflow and Keras packages. It took away almost 20 GBs of disks from my laptop.

My question was how to avoid such issue and make sure anaconda was only using the disks in, i.e. D drive?(in windows environment )

Answer (score 1):

try changing the paths of the environment variables

Comment: How? what's the variable name or variable value?

Comment: `conda config --add envs_dirs F:/anaconda3/envs`
Everything u install with `conda instsall` after this is going to be installed in F:/anaconda3/envs.